# proguard with applymapping produces duplicate names

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

I am writing an android module that is loaded into a 3rd party app as a plugin.  The API is provided by a `.jar` which has been obfuscated by proguard and contains a `mapping.txt` file.

In my proguard config I have:

```
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontshrink
-dontoptimize

-applymapping "mapping.txt"

...
```

The problem is, a class used only in my module gets mapped to the same name as a class used in the library `.jar` (but that I don't use).  When they are loaded at runtime this causes a `IncompatibleClassChangeError`.

I can clearly see the duplicates in the produced mapping files:

```
mine:
timber.log.Timber -> b.a.a:

jars:
gnu.nmea.ContainsPosition -> b.a.a:
```

Is there any way to make proguard *not* reuse obfusaction names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the rule

```
-repackageclasses <packagename>
```

in your Android module.
This will move all obfuscated classes into this (unique) package, avoiding name clashes.

Example: you module is named `com.foo.mymodule`, then you would add

```
 -repackageclasses com.foo.mymodule.internal
```

and all obfuscated classes will end up there.

Comment: This workaround appears to work, but the documentation warns about using it and referencing resource files.  Is there no way to tell proguard "don't use names already in the mapping file"?

Comment: No, and if you do not use resources then there should be no issue. This is the only way to create unique names, e.g. when using multiple modules / libraries that have been obfuscated with ProGuard or also obfuscate the consumer.

Comment: I actually *do* load a resource from "android.resources://", but I pull the package name from the context so I guess it's pulling the obfuscated name and finding it correctly.  I find this behavior very surprising, as I have several plugins (with identical proguard files) and the others don't seem to produce duplicate names.

Comment: The counter-indication for -repackageclasses is mainly for loading Java resources via ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream, but this does not make much sense for Android apps / module anyways.